polars parsing json with mixed data type arrays
Is it possible for polars to parse json that contains an array of mixed data types? In the example below, I have strings and objects in an array and can't figure out how to pass an acceptable schema to pl.read_json.
Here is an example of the data structure I'm working with:
import json
from io import StringIO

import polars as pl

json_input = StringIO(json.dumps({"data": [["group a", {"value": 100.0}]]}))

print(pl.read_json(json_input))  # is it possible to provide a valid schema here?

I would like to end up with:
shape: (1, 2)
┌─────────┬───────┐
│ group   ┆ value │
│ ---     ┆ ---   │
│ str     ┆ f64   │
╞═════════╪═══════╡
│ group a ┆ 100.0 │
└─────────┴───────┘


What would the resulting dataframe look like in this case?

I need to do some processing afterwards to achieve something like this: pl.DataFrame({"group": ["group a"], "value": [100.0]}). I was hoping I could unnest the inner object in the array somehow

I don't think it's possible with the json readers. I think you'd need to load it outside of Polars first, e.g. pl.DataFrame(json.loads(json_input.read())["data"], orient="row")

I'm thinking the same. Thanks for taking a look!
